# App Rejected Because of Advertising Identifier

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, idfa

My app got rejected from the App Store.

> If your app does not serve ads, please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to remove any instances of:
>
> `class: ASIdentifierManager`
>
> `selector: advertisingIdentifier`
>
> `framework: AdSupport.framework`
>
> If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please remove the Advertising Identifier from your app until you have included ad functionality.
>
> To help locate the Advertising Identifier, use the “nm” tool. For information on the “nm” tool, please see the nm man page.
>
> If you do not have access to the libraries' source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool lists the methods that the library calls, and "otool -ov" will list the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides.

I used the grep command and it showed me that the problem is with the Facebook Core Kit library. I need this library for the app to function but I can't get my app to the appstore with it.

I sent a message to the reviewers but they responded with the same message.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Your solution didn't help me, I'm not using the audience kit. The problem is with the core kit, which I can't remove.

Comment: Are you using App Events? If yes, the SDK will access the IDFA. When submitting for review (Apple) you usually get asked if you use the IDFA and AFAIK you have to say yes in that situation. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#IDFA